# Unable to open zip file in Python - BadZipFile error

Tags: python

When I create a zip file and try to open it in the same python code, why do I get BadZipFile error?

```
zip_file = "C:/Temp/tst_data_1022.txt"
filePath, fileName = os.path.split(zip_file)
baseFileName, fileExt = os.path.splitext(fileName)
destFtpFile = filePath + "/" + baseFileName + ".zip"

# Create the zip file and write to it
zFile = zipfile.ZipFile(destFtpFile, 'w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=True)
zFile.write(zip_file, arcname=fileName)

# Read Zip file
zfile = zipfile.ZipFile(destFtpFile, 'r')
for name in zfile.namelist():
    (dirname, filename) = os.path.split(name)
    print "Decompressing " + filename
    filename = "C:/Temp/" + filename
    fd = open(filename,"w")
    fd.write(zfile.read(name))
    fd.close()
```

The zip file is created correctly.
Error during reading:
    BadZipfile: File is not a zip file

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a call to `zFile.close()`, which will flush the remaining data that needs to be written to the zip file, and close the underlying file descriptor.